# MySQL - group rows in 4's

Tags: sql, mysql, grouping

I have a product table like this:

```
Product name , Affiliate ID , ProductCode
a, 1, 1
b, 1, 2
c, 1, 3
d, 1, 5
e, 1, 7
f, 2, 4
g, 2, 6
```

I want to return first four products from each Affiliate ID. The 'ProductCode' column signifies the order in which the products were added, so can I use this column to sort my results. But I don't know how to return the first four results from each Affiliate ID? If I use the 'group' function it returns only one row of each affiliate ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look to the example in this link:

[Within-group quotas (Top N per group)](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1920#104)

it is exactly that you need.

```
 SELECT AffiliateId, ProductCode 
 FROM ( 
    SELECT 
      AffiliateId, ProductCode, 
      IF( @prev <> ID  @rownum := 1, @rownum := @rownum+1 ) AS rank, 
      @prev := ID 
    FROM your table 
 JOIN (SELECT @rownum := NULL, @prev := 0) AS r 
 ORDER BY AffiliateId, ProductCode 
 ) AS tmp 
 WHERE tmp.rank <= 4
 ORDER BY AffiliateId, ProductCode;
```

Comment: Thanks - yes that looks like what I need. However I'm getting the following error: 

Query : SELECT `name`, productId, image, affiliate_id, productCode   FROM (       SELECT         `name`, productId, image, affiliate_id,...
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@rownum := 1, @rownum := @rownum+1 ) AS rank, 
      @prev := ID 
    FROM `Cu' at line 5
Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000

Comment: @Joe What is your mysql version?

Comment: My updated query: 

 SELECT tmp.`name`, tmp.productId, tmp.image, tmp.affiliate_id, tmp.productCode
 FROM ( 
    SELECT 
      `name`, productId, image, affiliate_id, productCode,
      IF( @PREV <> ID @rownum := 1, @rownum := @rownum+1 ) AS rank, 
      @PREV := affiliate_id
    FROM `CubeCart_inventory` t
 JOIN (SELECT @rownum := NULL, @PREV := 0) AS r 
 ORDER BY t.affiliate_id, t.productCode 
 ) AS tmp 
 WHERE tmp.rank <= 4
 ORDER BY affiliate_id, productCode;

Comment: also try add before query SET @rownum := NULL, @prev := NULL;

Comment: Fixed it - there was a comma missing in that line, and I needed to substitute ID for affiliate_id - working now, thanks so much!!